# Remove "Using default security password" on Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, testing, spring-security

I have a multi module project, I noticed that when I run my tests (for example the tests annotated with `@WebMvcTest`) I get this message

```
    Using generated security password: 12e4c462-385v-12y6-917u-e8u5rte36ooi
        
This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.
```

How do i remove it?
I think the "problem" is just that having a multi module project, in some tests, the class implementing `UserDetailsService` is not found because it is part of a different module and therefore the package is not scanned.
Is it enough for me to just ignore the message?
Actually this didn't happen before, it has happened since I removed a bean, probably useless, inside the `WebSecuriyConfig` class which extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
     @Bean
     @Override
     public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
         return super.authenticationManagerBean();
     }
```

Since I don't use that bean anywhere in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Security configuration is not loaded by default by `@WebMvcTest`. **You need to manually `@Import` your web-security config** and then setup test security-context.

For configuring OAuth2 test security context, you can use either

- MockMvc request post-processor: `jwt()` or `opaqueToken()` from `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors`)
- a test annotation from [this repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)

Sample with `@WithMockJwtAuth`

```java
@WebMvcTest()
@Import({ WebSecurityConfig.class })
class GreetingControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = {"NICE", "AUTHOR"}, claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferred_username = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void whenGrantedNiceRoleThenOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hi Tonton Pirate! You are granted with: [NICE, AUTHOR]."));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = {"AUTHOR"}, claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferred_username = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void whenNotGrantedNiceRoleThenForbidden() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    void whenAnonymousThenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
}
```

Same sample with `jwt` post-processor

```java
@WebMvcTest()
@Import({ WebSecurityConfig.class })
class GreetingControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void whenGrantedNiceRoleThenOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet").with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> {
            jwt.claim("preferred_username", "Tonton Pirate");
        }).authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("NICE"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("AUTHOR"))))).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hi Tonton Pirate! You are granted with: [NICE, AUTHOR]."));
    }

    @Test
    void whenNotGrantedNiceRoleThenForbidden() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet").with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> {
            jwt.claim("preferred_username", "Tonton Pirate");
        }).authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("AUTHOR"))))).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    void whenAnonymousThenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
}
```